# Compare values of keys in Python list with multiple dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a list made up of dictionaries. What I need to do is compare the value of key "a" (172.60) in one dictionary, and if it is 30% greater than the key "b" (168.80) value in the same dictionary then print the value of "value". And iterate over all of the dictionaries in the entire list.I have tried many different 'for' and 'if' constructs but the solution escapes me. I am using python v2.6.6.

```
List1= [{"p":0,"c":0,"b":168.80,"a":172.60,"oi":0,"vol":0,"value":355.00},
        {"p":0,"c":0,"b":163.80,"a":167.60,"oi":0,"vol":0,"value":360.00}]
```

Comment: So you compare the key "a" of one dictionary with the others... and print wherever that first key is larger than any the others by 30%. Then you iterate over the other dictionaries and do the same, correct? but you don't compare in between dictionaries or, for example, the key "b" with the key "p", is that correct?

Comment: Unrelated question, is this an exercise for school or similar?

Comment: I only need to compare the values of 'a' and 'b' to see if 'a'is 30% or more greater than 'b', no other keys need to be compared. Right, no need to compare values between different dictionaries.

Comment: This is not for school, just a weekend project that has been kicking my a**. I am far to old for school.

Comment: To help you out if you had a dictionary a you can do... For key in a:

Comment: assuming a is the list of dictionaries in the question, then ``[x['value'] for x in a if (x['a']*1.3 > x['b'])]``

Comment: @Vorsprung that will falsely report some `a` values that are less than `b`, need to reverse your multiplication as in @Jblascos answer

Comment: Do you want exactly 30% greater, more than 30% greater, or 30% or more greater?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
for dd in List1:
    if dd["a"] > 1.3 * dd["b"]:
        print dd["value"]
```